# Flutter: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'selection' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I have a separate class which lays out radio buttons on the homepage in a separate class. 
Radio Class:
Below is from TYPE enum which contains two values regular and nonregular:
TYPE _dtype = TYPE.regular;

```js
Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 180.0,
            child: RadioListTile<TYPE>(
              title: Text(
                'Regular' ,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              value: TYPE.regular,
              groupValue: _dtype,
              onChanged: (TYPE value) { setState(() { _dtype = value; }); },
            ),
          ),


          Container(
            width: 186.0,

            child:RadioListTile<TYPE>(
              title: const Text('Non Regular',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              value: TYPE.nonregular,
              groupValue: _dtype,
              onChanged: (TYPE value) { setState(() { _dtype = value; }); },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

i have couple of questions:

1. Is it possible to autosize the radio w.r.t. text in it? As without supplying width property, radio doesnot appear on screen.
2. Once one of the radio is selected, I want to pass the value..._dtype to homepage class to do some work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace your `Container` with `Expanded` and remove the width attribute. This will automatically set each child of the row to occupy an equal amount of space.

To explain why this is necessary, `RadioListTile` will expand to take as much space as is available, and `Container` will be as big as its child if no size is specified. Since `Row` has infinite width and there's no width constraint between it and your `RadioListTile`, it's trying to expand to take up an infinite amount of width, so it won't render. `Expanded` automatically calculates and applies a width here, so it'll fix the issue and work well no matter the screen size.

2. Pass a callback function to your new widget. Flutter generally prefers sending data down the tree than up, so sending a callback function down to your button is a bit easier than sending the data up for your parent widget to handle, and it'll wind up having the same effect.

```
class YourRadioGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  void Function(TYPE) doSomething = (t) {};

  YourRadioGrid({this.doSomething});

  ...

  onPressed: (TYPE value) {
    doSomething(value);
  }
}

// Then wherever in your homepage's build method this gets added:

YourRadioGrid(doSomething: (value) { /*handle the new value*/ })
```